Problem understanding a bitwise XOR operation code in rust
I have the following code, the purpose of it is to find 14 distinct letters in a string of letters. It does it by using a left shift and XOR operator, I don't fully understand why the left shift is needed and how the XOR operator works here, in the following code I use the string 'abcdefghijklmno'.
The result of filter in binary after setting b is: 00000000000000000000000000000110
The binary value of c after left shift is 00011, using a XOR operator should result in
00000000000000000000000000000100 but the result is 00000000000000000000000000001110.
So far I've only gotten that "the values being XOR-ed are not identical because they represent different bit patterns corresponding to different characters"
I really don't understand how this works, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.
pub fn benny(input: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
   let mut filter = 0u32;
   
   // Print the initial value of filter
   println!("Initial value of filter: {:032b}", filter);

   input.iter().take(14 - 1).for_each(|&c| {
       let c_shifted = c as u32 % 32;
       filter ^= 1 << c_shifted;

       // Print the value of filter after setting each character
       println!("Value of filter after setting '{}' (left shift: {}, binary value: {:05b}): {:032b}", c as char, c_shifted, c_shifted, filter);
   });

   input.windows(14).position(|w| {
       let first = w[0];
       let last = w[w.len() - 1];
       filter ^= 1 << (last % 32);
       let res = filter.count_ones() == 14 as u32;
       filter ^= 1 << (first % 32);

       // Print the value of filter after processing each window
       println!("Value of filter after processing window: {:032b}", filter);

       res
   })
}


fn main() {
   let word_list = b"abcdefghijklmno";
   let result = benny(word_list);
   println!("Result: {:?}", result);
}


You are XOR'ing 1 << c_shifted, not c_shifted.

"The binary value of c after left shift is 00011", no, the binary value of c without left shift is 00011. After left shift it is (1 << 3) == 1000.
